# Quill editor in angular validation

Tags: angular, quill

We are working with Angular 7 and using quill-editor for the editor.

The code of quill editor is below :

```
 <quill-editor required id="myText" [(ngModel)]="modalPresentation.myText" [styles]="{height: '250px'}" name="myText"></quill-editor>
```

I have to made it required field, it's working with required, but if I do not enter anything and or anything gets deleted and I click on another side of the window then it should show red-bordered around Quill Editor as a sign of required.

I want to do it using CSS styles, I tried but the solutions not working.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Have you reffered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946620/how-to-make-quill-editor-required